# Remove class add class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I have this jQuery content toggle setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/848/

I am trying to remove the class for the span that contains the plus glyphicon and replace it with the minus glyphicon when the content is visible.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#toggle-view li').click(function () {

        var text = $(this).children('div.panel');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('-');     
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('+');     
        }

    });

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="toggle-view">
    <li class="li-toggle">
        <h3 class="toggle-h3">Title 1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h3>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried implementing this code to try and remove the plus glyph and replace it with the minus glyph however I can't get it to work:

```
$(this).children('span')removeClass(glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle).addClass(glyphicon glyphicon-minus glyph-minus-toggle);
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: are you not giving `.` before `removeClass` in your code also, are it just a typo while posting the question.

Comment: Quotes are missing too.

Comment: Review the code you pasted here in your question. It is missing parts (compared to the one in the link you gave)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addClass` and `removeClass` functions require strings, to know what classes you are talking about. A string is declared by putting quotes around the text. Because those are missing, it now thinks those are variables, which they aren't.

Added to that, you were missing a dot before `removeClass`.

Try this:

```
$(this).children('span').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-minus glyph-minus-toggle");
```

---

Edit: I changed it, and it works: [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koedood/DTcHh/858/)

The problem was your use of `.children()`. I changed it with `.find()`. Taken from [this](http://api.jquery.com/children/) page:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Since the elements you were looking for aren't direct children, they didn't get selected.

Comment: Thanks I have tried implementing this in the fiddle however they still aren't changing, I hate to be cheeky but could you show me a fiddle example?

Comment: @NickMaddren I have updated the answer for you. I hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: @SanderKoedood, almost right. You switched the 'plus'/'minus' positions in the code. Also, you don't need the `.html()` call anymore.

Comment: @ericbn Thank you, you are right. I edited it according to your comment.

Comment: Thanks guys awesome help here! I've just changed the CSS so that the minus floats right and it's working perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

1. You put `removeClass` right after the children() function, without using a dot.
2. You didn't use brackets (" or ') for your string.
3. You've tried to remove/append multiple classes at once by seprating the classes with a space. I don't think this is possible.

Also, you put a number in a string, wich is unnecessary. You don't need to use brackets if you want to have an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure about .children() method...

You can try find() like this and just use .addClass("classname") or .removeClass("classname"). Note that "." (dots) are not needed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#toggle-view li').click(function () {

    var text = $(this).children('div.panel');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        $(this).find('span').removeClass("glyphicon-plus");
        $(this).find('span').addClass("glyphicon-minus");   
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
        $(this).find('span').addClass("glyphicon-plus");
        $(this).find('span').removeClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }

 });
});
```